# Git command to get HEAD SHA1 with "-dirty" suffix if workspace is not clean

Tags: git

I'm working to add a version number to a build process. For versions built on developer machines, I want to know whether the workspace contained changes that may have been included in the build, and suffix the SHA1 with `-dirty`.

For example:

```
c2bc0d223739c841c5e810c6c439562aa9d67f5f
c2bc0d223739c841c5e810c6c439562aa9d67f5f-dirty
```

The first form can be obtained via:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

However I cannot work out how to append the `-dirty` suffix when the workspace is dirty. `git describe` provides this, but only on tag names. We don't really use tags (the last was 400 or so revisions ago) and they're not as conclusive as the SHA1.

Can this be done in a single command or will I need to do some bash scripting?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `--match` with something that's never going to match to force describe to not match any tags. It's a bit hackish but it works:

```
git describe --match=NeVeRmAtCh --always --abbrev=40 --dirty
```

Comment: Is it still the best way to do it?

Comment: I didn't seem to need `--match` myself (there's also a `--no-match` option).  what cases did `--match=...` make a difference?

Comment: @AnthonySottile If you don't include `--match=NeVeRmAtCh` the output will contain the tag also.

Comment: You could also pass an empty string to the `--match` option: `--match=""`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I took the accepted answer and found the bare minimum version that worked.

```
git describe --always --dirty
```

Comment: Did you verify this won't output a tag name when the commit has a tag?

Comment: For my use case that’d actually be preferred. The OP said they don’t use tags ‍♂️